# how can i stop the mouse from opening docs, etc with one click in ubuntu?

Tags: mouse

I cannot stop my mouse from opening docs, etc. with one click.  There is no option to change this in mouse settings.  I want to open files by double clicking--not single clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Nautilus setting...

Edit->Preferences->Bihavior tab:

- Single click to open items
- Double click to open items

The following command should also do the job:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences click-policy double
```